# Insomnia rest client error

Tags: rest, api, rest-client, insomnia

When I do a POST request I am getting this error.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000.
On the contrary, when I use postman it works.

This is the url:
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in

And this is my configuration:

JSON tab:

```
{"user": {"email": "user@nivelr.com", "password": "clave12345"}}
```

Headers:

- Accept        application/json
- Content-Type  application/json

Comment: Let's just hope this isn't a password you use else where

Comment: it's just an example.

Answer (score 9):

I'm the developer of Insomnia, and would like to let you know that this problem has been fixed in a recent release.

The app will now first attempt an IPv6 lookup (usually ::1), then fallback to an IPv4 lookup (usually 127.0.0.1) on error. This now aligns with the behavior of the `curl` command line tool.

You can download the latest version [here](https://insomnia.rest/download/) for Mac, Windows, or Linux.

Comment: what is use of operationid in every single api. what is its functionality and use?

Comment: @gschier thanks for that - FYI I was having this issue with Insomnia v2021.2.0 on Windows Server 2016, but updating to v2021.2.1 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late here obviously, but if you've never figured it out, using `http://[::1]` instead of `http://localhost` solved this issue for me. It seems that some servers (in my case, Rust's Iron), when told to listen on localhost, interpret it as IPv6 (`[::1]`), hence the IPv4 address stops working.